# Pentaho merge two tables

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I'm new to Pentaho.

This is the transformation I'm trying to do:
Import Transactions and Merchant and merge these two tables using `MERCH_KEY`

However, this isn't working, see below:

[image]

This is table `Transactions`:

[image]

And this is table `Merchant`:

[image]

And this is the `Merge join`:

[image]

This all seems good, but it's not working and I have no idea why.
From the preview, I can see the two tables are being imported, so how can I merge them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all fields except "MERCH_KEY" from the right-side list.

The Merge join step is a little misleading with its behavior, as it only allows you to click Get Fields and get ALL fields, but doesn't let you pick a single field in a dropdown.

As the name suggest, these are the key fields that will be compared in the join, so fields need to be in the correct order. In your case, you only need the one. The other input fields (from both tables) will be automatically added to the output stream, with fields from the second table getting renamed if duplicated.